# How do I do a `git add` with vc-git?

Tags: git, vc

I want to stage a file or a hunk using vc-git (the vc system that comes with Emacs). How do I do this?

(To clarify, I made modifications on a file that is already (registered) in git. I would like to stage the new modifications made. How do I do this with vc-git?)

Comment: Have a look at `vc-git-register`, which does a  little bit more -- the first argument needs to be in list form.  If you want it to do less, then you may need to create a custom function.  To see what makes it tick, you can use `M-x find-function`.

Comment: While VC has grown some features specifically for Git, it hasn't grown anything like Git's staging, so `vc-git` does not provide any means to manipulate Git's "index", instead it tries hard to *hide* it.  You'll probably be better served by Magit if you want to use that kind of Git feature from Emacs.

Comment: @Stefan But one can stage and commit only marked files in vc-dir. Though it is not possible to stage hunks.

Answer (score 4):

`C-x v v` will run `vc-next-action` command.

> Do the next logical version control operation on the current fileset.
>   This requires that all files in the current VC fileset be in the
>   same state.  If not, signal an error.
>
> For merging-based version control systems:
>
> - If every file in the VC fileset is not registered for version
>     control, register the fileset (but don’t commit).
> - If every work file in the VC fileset is added or changed, pop
>     up a `*vc-log*` buffer to commit the fileset.